# Why am I getting a syntax error on this INTO command?

Tags: sql, syntax

UPDATE: It helps if you put the data `INTO` your table first. I adjusted the code and it works!

I am working in SQL and I want to count unique titles within a table. The top code is a query I wrote to count by employee number, select the title column from the `unique_titles` table, group by the title, and create a new table in descending order. The bottom code is, obviously a syntax error. I'm not sure this code is correct but the `INTO` statement looks correct to me:

```
SELECT COUNT (unique_titles.emp.no), unique_titles.title
FROM unique_titles
GROUP BY unique_titles.title
INTO retiring_titles
ORDER BY DESC;
```

````
LINE 4: INTO retiring_titles
        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 107```
````

Comment: [The Basics](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: INTO should be after SELECT (This is basic, you should google before posting question if you don't want down vote)

SELECT ...
INTO
FROM

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(unique_titles.id)
INTO retiring_titles
FROM unique_titles
GROUP BY unique_titles.title
ORDER BY DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` can help you.

It has folowing structre. Example:

```
CREATE TABLE suppliers
  AS (SELECT company_id, address, city, state, zip
      FROM companies
      WHERE company_id < 5000);
```

In your case you can try something like:

```
CREATE TABLE retiring_titles
as (
SELECT count(distinct unique_titles.id) from unique_title
)
```